# Can we make the blog more visible on the main site?

Tags: support, feature-request, blog

As @lqlarry mentioned in his [answer](https://diy.meta.stackexchange.com/a/540/33) to this [question](https://diy.meta.stackexchange.com/q/539/33), it might help the blog gain traction if it were more visible.

Is it possible to put a permanent link to the blog on the main site?  Instead of replacing a link only when new content is available, could we leave the link there all the time?

It might also be nice if when new content was available, we could display the banner (similar to when a chat event is coming up) so users could know there's new stuff to read.

#### UPDATE:

Maybe the Community Bulletin board will help.

[image]

Comment: What blog? Where is the link?

Comment: @ppumkin If you scroll way down to the bottom of the site, you'll find the link. Or use [This one](http://diy.blogoverflow.com/).

Answer (score 1):

I wonder if we used the add in the right column (I think this is the banner you are talking about) how often can we change it?  It would be nice to be able to change that add every hour or two and then we can take care of the Blog, Facebook, Google+, Captain Construction (dah-dohn-dahhhhh) and whatever else we need and also share with other SE sites, like having them on our site as well.  Today [ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/) has an add for their newsletter, which would be a good idea for us also.

Also, how many adds can we have? Just one?

If someone can give me which SE site would probably already have answered questions like this let me know and I'll do some searching when I get home.  Lunch is almost over for me.

Comment: We can have ads for whatever we want. [See](http://meta.diy.stackexchange.com/q/461/33), we just have to make them and vote for them.